# Inserting Enum values to table using hibernate

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, enums

I need to populate Employee table having a Gender field with possible values 1--> Male, 2 --> Female

Hibernate Mapping for the table:

```
package test.hib.entity;

import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Convert;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.EnumType;
import javax.persistence.Enumerated;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

import test.hib.enumtest.GenderConverter;

@Entity
@Table(name="Employee")
public class Employee implements Serializable {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -2531499686831259894L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int employeeId;

    @Column
    private String employeeName;

    @Column
    @Convert(converter=GenderConverter.class)
    private Gender gender;

    public int getEmployeeId() {
        return employeeId;
    }

    public void setEmployeeId(int employeeId) {
        this.employeeId = employeeId;
    }

    public String getEmployeeName() {
        return employeeName;
    }

    public void setEmployeeName(String employeeName) {
        this.employeeName = employeeName;
    }

    public Gender getGender() {
        return gender;
    }

    public void setGender(Gender gender) {
        this.gender = gender;
    }




}
```

Gender Enum:

```
package test.hib.entity;

public enum Gender {
    MALE(1),
    FEMALE(2);

    private int value;

    private Gender(int value){
        this.value = value;
    }

    public int getValue() {
        return value;
    }



    public static Gender getGender(Integer id) {
        if (id == null)
            return null;
        for (Gender g : values()) {
            if (g.getValue() == id)
                return g;
        }
        return null;
    }

}
```

Converter:

```
package test.hib.enumtest;

import javax.persistence.AttributeConverter;
import javax.persistence.Converter;

import test.hib.entity.Gender;

@Converter
public class GenderConverter implements AttributeConverter<Gender, Integer>{

    @Override
    public Integer convertToDatabaseColumn(Gender arg0) {
        if(arg0 != null) return arg0.getValue();
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public Gender convertToEntityAttribute(Integer arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return Gender.getGender(arg0);
    }

}
```

I use the following code to modify the entity,

```
ApplicationContext applicationContext = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("springConfig.xml");
HibEnumRepo repository = (HibEnumRepo)applicationContext.getBean(HibEnumRepo.class);

Employee employee = new Employee();
employee.setEmployeeName("Renjith");
employee.setGender(Gender.MALE);


repository.insertEmployee(employee);

Employee employee2 = new Employee();
employee2.setEmployeeName("Renju");
employee2.setGender(Gender.FEMALE);


repository.insertEmployee(employee2);
```

inside repository bean.

```
package test.hib.enumtest;

import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

import test.hib.entity.Employee;

    @Repository
    public class HibEnumRepo {

        @Autowired
        private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

        @Transactional
        public void insertEmployee(Employee employee){
            Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();

            session.save(employee);
        }
    }
```

But on inserting the values to table, the Enum is setting the default values for Male & Female ie. 0 & 1 respectively.

```
mysql> select * from Employee;
+------------+--------------+--------+
| employeeId | employeeName | gender |
+------------+--------------+--------+
|          1 | Renjith      |      0 |
|          2 | Renju        |      1 |
+------------+--------------+--------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

How can i set the value 1 & 2 instead?

Comment: Is there some external reason why you need to use non-default numerals?

Comment: @chrylis. i did it for study purpose.

Comment: As a broad-level note, if you're using Postgres, Hibernate can use database enum types to get the best of both worlds--readable values in a SELECT statement and integer-speed lookup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is better to store the `enum` as `String` in the DB and retrieve its id from application using the `enum`.

You are persisting the `EnumType.ORDINAL` of the `enum` which starts from 0, that is the reason 0 and 1 are getting persisted in DB

If you want the enum's id to be persisted you can use `Coverter` annotation

**Convert added in JPA2.1 (Hibernate 4.3+)**

Entity

```
@Entity
public class Employee {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    Long id;

    @Column
    String name;

    @Column
    int age;

    @Column
    @Convert(converter = GenderConverter.class)
    Gender gender;
}
```

converter

```
public class GenderConverter implements AttributeConverter<Gender, Integer> {

    @Override
    public Integer convertToDatabaseColumn(Gender gender) {
        if (gender == null)
            return null;
        return gender.getId();
    }

    @Override
    public Gender convertToEntityAttribute(Integer id) {
        return Gender.getGender(id);
    }

}
```

Enum

```
public enum Gender {
    MALE(1), FEMALE(2);
    int id;

    private Gender(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public static Gender getGender(Integer id) {
        if (id == null)
            return null;
        for (Gender g : values()) {
            if (g.getId() == id)
                return g;
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

DDL Created by hibernate

```
Hibernate: create table employee (id bigint generated by default as identity, age integer, gender integer, name varchar(255), primary key (id))
```

Comment: looks promising..... but don't know why it is still not working !! Updated my Question

Comment: I used JPA with Hibernate, did you debug the converter methods?

Comment: Yes, it is not even going into those methods. I even tried @Converter annotation at class level.

Comment: @Renju it could be due to the lower version of hibernate? what version are using? and try updating hibernate to `4.3+`

Comment: @Renju `Convert` was added in `JPA2.1` and corresponding implementation of hibernate is `4.3+`, so you should update hibernate for `Convert` to work

Comment: @Renju have a look at http://hibernate.org/orm/downloads/ for JPA vs Hibernate mapping

Comment: ok. was using '<version>4.1.4.Final</version>'. Let me try with the latest.